# Rollback statement Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-administration, rollback, rollbacksegments

I'm new to dba in oracle. Im just learning about rollback segment. I have a few questions about it, it'll be great if i can find some help here.

1- after issuing a dml statement, does the most valid data exists in redo log files or rollback statement?

2- is the rollback statement ever used in a ddl statement?

---

Comment: Do you mean "statement" or "segment"?  The rollback statement is a SQL command.  A rollback segment is an old way to describe what is now called UNDO.  What does "most valid data" mean?  The current, uncommitted data?  The previous, committed data?

Comment: In Oracle, DDL is automatic commit. Can't rollback

Answer (score 0):

You can (loosely) think of redo and undo as instructions.

For example, you drove from home to the shop. That is a change in your "state", ie, 20 mins ago you were at home, now you are at the shop.

The redo information would be:

- grab the keys
- start the car
- drive down Main st
- turn left into North ave
- turn right into parking lot
- park car

It is a list of instructions that would let you (aka the database) repeat a task (for example, during a database recovery).

The undo information is *not* about remembering your previous state (you were at home), but more a set of instructions on how to return to a previous state. In this case it would be:

- get back in the car
- head out of the parking lot
- turn right into North St
- head back down Main st
- pull into the driveway
- get out of the car
- chill out on the couch

This information is stored in the undo (or rollback) segments in the database.

A video walk through of the process is at

https://youtu.be/lmrWmH1vMPc?t=66